# sass -v point to the wrong version

Tags: rubygems, sass

I've two version of sass installed on my machine:

1. sass-3.2.19 (bundle)
2. sass-3.3.8

With one of my computer when I do SASS -v I see:

sass-3.3.8

With the other I see:

sass-3.2.19

The one that show me  "sass-3.2.19" cause me several error when I compile my projects (using framework like bourbon/neat/susy..) because it use too advanced syntrax.

How can I make also the second machine point to version  sass-3.3.8?

p.s. I can't specify 3.3.8 in the gemfile because i'm using middleman or compass and they need version 3.2

Thanks for any tips

Comment: Are you not able to upgrade Compass or Middleman?  Because you can't use Sass 3.3 with Compass 0.12, they are incompatible.

Comment: I'm not using compass, is just there :) Middleman no, you can't upgrade and i already wrote to the team, they say they are waiting for a compass upgrade before upgrade middleman...

Comment: I know i can't use sass 3.3 with compass 0.12 or middleman but i need to change the version where my sass is pointing, like my other computer already does. So my bundle still look at sass 3.2 (and middleman is happy) but my machine use sass 3.3. and bourbon/susy/neat/... are happy too :)

Comment: `sass --version` should only ever display the newest version, do you actually have Sass 3.3 installed on both machines?

Comment: yes, that i'm sure. If i do gem list i can see both versions in both machines